# How to use ulimit in a shell environment to limit memory?

Tags: unix, ulimit

I'm trying the set the maximum memory usage of a command with `ulimit`.
My command is currently:

```
ulimit -m 1024 -v 0; python file.py
```

The python process uses over 5MB of memory. What have I done wrong with the `ulimit` command?

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage? Maybe look into the `-d` and `-s` limits also.

Comment: @tripleee `ulimit` says it's kbytes, so 1024 would be 1mbyte right?

Comment: @tripleee Seems I misunderstood your question, I am using Activity Monitor on Mac 10.9 to measure the memory usage.

Comment: So does it measure stack or heap or physical or virtual memory consumption, or what?

Comment: @tripleee It appears to measure Real Memory